# VBA - IF Not Intersect only working once

Tags: excel, vba

I am attempting to trigger a sort every time a date is entered into a specific range of cells. The code below is functioning but only once when I first open the workbook. If I perform another operation or enter more than one date, it is not repeating?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    .DisplayAlerts = False
End With

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("H4:H2500")) Is Nothing Then

        Rows("4:2500").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Detail_Plan").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Detail_Plan").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range( _
        "H4:H2500"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
        xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Detail_Plan").Sort
        .SetRange Range("A4:AU2500")
        .Header = xlGuess
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With

    End If

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .EnableEvents = False
    .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    .DisplayAlerts = True
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Seems like a simple typo...

Comment: Change `Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)` to `Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)` because earlier one will execute the code as soon as you select any range which I don't think is desired here the latter one will execute the macro when you change any value or enter any value which I think is desired.

Comment: Vacip - As someone who is attempting to teach themselves VBA and learn from the experience of others (Remind you of your quote by Douglas Adams?), it's disappointing to encounter those similar to yourself who feel the need to observe, judge, and not participate in assisting with a resolution. The world would be better off if talented people, such as yourself, would push themselves to exhibit more respect towards others.

Comment: Newguy - That seems to disable the code. With that modification, nothing happens. Thank you for your help.

Comment: After making that change you have to change any value and not just select in the `Range("H4:H2500")` otherwise it will not work.

Comment: I am modifying several cells in the Range("H4:H2500") and a sort is still not taking place. I believe something else might be going on but don't know what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're not re enabling events when you're done, selection change is an event

```
With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .EnableEvents = True
    .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    .DisplayAlerts = True
End With
```

Comment: You were absolutely correct. After I asked the question, I noticed I had another problem going on. The selection is actually taking place before I enter information. It's happening as soon as I click on the cell. This is making it impossible to change a value. Any ideas?

Comment: You need to change it to a Private Sub Worksheet_Change to trigger a macro every time a cell changes. If that isn't working like you mention above, put a line break in somewhere to debug it and see if the problem is that the macro isn't firing or if something else isn't going on

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim formule As String
    Dim col As Integer

    ' Il existe un changement potentiel Alerte <--> Véto
    If Not Intersect(Onglet_Formulaire.Range("AV_Type"), Target) Is Nothing Then
       Application.ScreenUpdating = False
       Onglet_Formulaire.Unprotect
       Onglet_Administration.Unprotect

       If Onglet_Formulaire.Range("LangueChoisie").Value = "FR" Then col = 1 Else col = 2

        ' Mises à jour sur la feuille formulaire
        With Onglet_Formulaire
            If .Range("AV_Type").Value = "Véto" Or .Range("AV_Type").Value = "Veto" Then
                formule = .Range("TitreFormulaire").Formula
                formule = Replace(formule, "F1_C01", "F1_C02")
                .Range("TitreFormulaire").Formula = formule
                .Range("ChoixAlerteVeto").Value = "Veto"
                ColorierContours
            Else
                formule = .Range("TitreFormulaire").Formula
                formule = Replace(formule, "F1_C02", "F1_C01")
                .Range("TitreFormulaire").Formula = formule
                .Range("ChoixAlerteVeto").Value = "Alerte"
                ColorierContours
            End If
            If .Range("AV_Type").Value = "" Then
                If .Range("LangueChoisie").Value = "FR" Then
                    .Range("AV_Type").Value = "Alerte"
                Else
                    .Range("AV_Type").Value = "Alert"
                End If
            End If

            If .Range("AV_Type").Value = "Véto" Or .Range("AV_Type").Value = "Veto" Then
                AssocierListe "Statut", "ChoixStatutVeto", col
            Else
                AssocierListe "Statut", "ChoixStatutAlerte", col
            End If
        End With

        Onglet_Formulaire.Protect DrawingObjects:=True, _
            Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True, AllowFormattingColumns:=True, AllowFormattingRows:=True
        Onglet_Administration.Protect

        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End If
End Sub


Private Sub WorkSheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
    '
    ' Gestion de la cellule Type d'Impact
    '
    If Target.Count = 1 And Target.Row = Range("AV_Type_Impact").Row And _
            Target.Column = Range("AV_Type_Impact").Column And _
            Not Gestion_Type_Impact.IsAffiché Then
        Gestion_Type_Impact.Afficher
    Else
        If Gestion_Type_Impact.IsAffiché Then
            Gestion_Type_Impact.Valider
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.